# Basic Discord Self-Bot Throwing 'Intents' Error On Script Run

Tags: python, discord, bots

Attempting to follow an "updated" version of a Self-Bot tutorial for Discord. I have (I believe) everything setup to make said self-bot. I have some very basic Python experience, but absolutely none when it comes to using Python with Discord. At this moment the main.py will not run due to an error which I am absolutely beat at troubleshooting myself.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', self_bot=True)

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong!')

TOKEN = 'xxx'
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

[The Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uLw3.png)

I tried using what an older StackOverflow question recommended, and inserted a line of code related to the 'intents' the error is referencing, but was given the same error upon attempting to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Self-bots are against Discord TOS and have been long removed from discord.py. I suggest you follow a more up-to-date tutorial and use a library that explicitly supports self-botting such as [discum](https://pypi.org/project/discum/).

Answer (score -1):

The constructor to the `Bot` class you are using requires an `Intents` object as a parameter.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)
```

Intents control what events your bot receives, some require special permissions and need to be enabled in the Developer Portal. For more details read [the discordpy docs about intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html).

Also I believe the `self_bot` parameter has been removed. So your Tutorial might not be "updated"